# Android & Netbeans: "Stopped unexpectedly"

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android, but OK with Java, and prefer Netbeans to Eclipse. I'm trying to get the HelloAndroid app running, without success.

```
package com.ex.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText("Hello, Android");
   setContentView(tv);
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ex.helloandroid"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="HelloAndroid"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This compiles OK, and installs OK in both the emulator and my phone. But when I try to run it, I get the dreaded "The application HelloAndroid (process com.ex.helloandroid) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Here's the logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager(   70): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ex.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid }
I/ActivityManager(   70): Start proc com.ex.helloandroid for activity com.ex.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid: pid=691 uid=10036 gids={1015}
D/AndroidRuntime(  691): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  691): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ex.helloandroid/com.ex.helloandroid.HelloAndroid}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ex.helloandroid.HelloAndroid in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/dat
a/app/com.ex.helloandroid-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ex.helloandroid.HelloAndroid in loader dalvik.system.PathC
lassLoader[/data/app/com.ex.helloandroid-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
E/AndroidRuntime(  691):        ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(   70):   Force finishing activity com.ex.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid
W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45422d20 com.ex.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid}
W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{45422d20 com.ex.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid}
I/Process (  691): Sending signal. PID: 691 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(   70): Process com.ex.helloandroid (pid 691) has died.
W/InputManagerService(   70): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Prox
y@451f4560
```

I've spent days trying to make this work... installed a new copy of Netbeans, reinstalled NBAndroid, reinstalled Android SDK, Googled and fiddled with the code. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Frank

Answer (score 0):

The project seems to run fine. I used your Activity and manifest and there were no problems. Try cleaning your project. GO to **Project-->Clean**

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I was trying to link a Java library to the Android project, and had regressed my source code all the way back to vanilla HelloAndroid. But hadn't removed the library from the Android project. So it appears that the problem is something to do with linking a Java Library project to the Android app... even if the app doesn't use anything in the library, the fact that it's there causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Put your main.xml. Use DroidDraw to create main.xml and call `setContentView(R.layout.main);` instead of `setContentView(tv);`